Passport picture with hair but I’m bald now
I applied for a new passport 2 years ago and still had medium-length hair at the time. Now the 2 years have passed and I have a bald head. Could this cause me any problems when traveling outside the EU?

No facial recognition system, including a human border guard or immigration officer, relies on things that can be changed, like hair.  It's all about structure; relative position of eyes, nose, mouth and ears.  If you have a biometric passport (quite likely if it's issued within the EU in the last two years) that's also usually increases confidence in your id, as they're very hard to forge.

@StephenG-HelpUkraine Well, I have anecdotal counter-evidence: When I tried to enter "socialist" East Berlin for a day trip from West Berlin in the 1980s, I had a passport with a full beard which I had, meanwhile, shaved off. The East German immigration officer hummed and hawed, fetched his superior, who hummed and hawed and eventually told me: "You know, we could let you in, but you would not get out again." I thanked him for his frankness and foresight and went home instead. That was, of course, before biometric data was stored in the passports.

A Singapore lady I met abroad complained that the border security people often gave her second looks. She thought that everyone applied a "beauty" filter to their photo.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica You have to assume a fully competent and generally incorruptible border force in this circumstance. I believe East Germany had neither. This advice really can only apply to open, democratic states where border guards don't demand bribes or turn you away because they just don't like your face.

@Crazymoomin GDR border officers were typically neither corrupt nor incompetent -- unfortunately.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica I'm not so sure about that, the British Army didn't trust them!

If you're very worried about it, just renew your passport early supplying a recent photograph.  Last couple of times I've renewed my passport I paid extra to expedite and it came back in a week.  Of course that costs money.

Your face features are the main thing that is checked. Change of hair, especially considering passports are usually valid for 10 years, is very normal. In that duration many people grow their hair, cut it shorter, dye it another color, flatten it, curl it, or lose it entirely due to male pattern baldness or other reasons (chemotherapy etc).
If questioned (very unlikely), simply state the reason, and they'll be understanding. Realistically though, main thing to expect is that they may take a few extra looks at you to match more features, but that's about it. If you're traveling as a tourist this shouldn't extend your time at border in a noticeable manner (as it'll probably involve some questions that take at least a few minutes anyways), and in general shouldn't affect e-gate functionality.

Anecdotally, I know trans people, who had a bunch of changes after hormones incl. hair, still traveled on an older passport without issues (at most they were given some extra looks). Some countries may cause issues with that one, but that's mostly due to politics/culture/unfamiliarity, whereas baldness transcends both of those.

I did not experience any serious issue like being refused entry but I wouldn't say questions are very unlikely.

Same thing for eGates, not only do the eGates pick up on this but any doubtful match — of for all I know, all matches — is typically routed to an officer and can result in a delay (see my answer). Contrary to what's sometimes said, it's just not the case that border guards or eGates automagically compare unalterable features irrespective of facial hair.

you know that it shouldn't have even been a question https://fee.org/articles/passports-were-a-temporary-war-measure/

I have been in this exact situation for a couple of years (lost hair and grew a beard) and I have in fact been asked for additional documentation both when leaving the EU / Schengen area and when entering other countries.
In one case (entering the UK), I did not have any other form of photo ID but the officer was satisfied with the fact I had many other documents, credit cards, etc. with my name on it (presumably because creating a whole set of fake documents would be costly and it means it's less likely that the passport was stolen, falsified, or borrowed).
In another case, I already had newer documents with a more convincing photo on me (ID card, driving license) but the discrepancy between my passport photo and my current bald head was picked up when going through an “automated” passport check. I was locked in the gate until an officer came from the control room to talk to me (she didn't really ask anything, she just wanted to check my other documents and look at me directly rather than through a screen).

I had the reverse problem for a number of years. I had a crew-cut all the time I was married (my ex didn't like long hair), and when I got divorced then I grew my hair. Until I renewed my passport last year, there was a significant disconnect between the crew-cut passport photo and the shoulder-length reality.
I sometimes had passport officials take a second look to check, but I never had any problems.

At least in your case, as a last resort, you can cut your hair on the spot and get back to the picture. Concentrating very hard to make hair regrow is more of a challenge.

I'd say it's the other way around. A bald person can easily put on a wig; but cutting my hair would not happen voluntarily nor without incident...

Your current profile pic is so appropriate for this answer! (Cousin It?) A significant disconnect indeed.

@Graham that's not false either :)
